# How can I import a large mysql database with a FTP client?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, ftp

I have a large mysql database with 30 million users.

I need to import it to a brand new server. I tried using PHPMyAdmin's import function, but it says the file is too big.

When I was searching for a way to bypass this, some people said to edit the php.ini file.

I was wondering how I can do this with an FTP client? Which files must I copy and paste to the new server to successfully get the database working on it?

Comment: Upload Adminer in your FTP and gzip your .sql file, upload your compressed sql file and login in Adminer and try import...

Comment: Yes, but exactly to what location?

Comment: I used to do it like this: download adminer.php upload file in ftp base or root directory compressed. Sql file as gzip and upload in same location where adminer.php then login in adminer like www.site.com/adminer-xx-.php use mysql credentials to login select your desire db or if you have create db query in .sql file then import directly by using run after login in adminer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin's UploadDir feature was implemented to fix such a problem. Documentation at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=uploaddir#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems.